# NuGet Can't Install Packages

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, installation, nuget-package

I created a new .NET core Web App and I am trying to add packages `Microsoft.EntityframeworkCore` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore` and I am getting the error:

> package restore failed rolling back packages

I have tried clearing the NuGet Caches reinstalling VS 2017 and the problem persists, note the project is brand new.

Comment: Hi, does your issue is solved or not? If not, please share your test result in here.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your VS 2017 already upgraded to [15.3.5](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes), you can re-run the VS 2017 installer as administrator and if there has the ‘Update’ button, click it to update. Then check you also installed [the latest .NET Core 2.0 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core) and then create a new ASP.NET core web application, choose ‘ASP.NET Core 2.0’ as below to create:
[image]

Then you can successfully install those 2 packages through Manage Nuget Packages like the following:
[image]

Comment: @rahulchawla, so glad to hear that your issue is solved and if my reply is helpful, please mark it as an answer and thank you for voting it, that will help other community members who meet the same or similar issue to easier to search it, thanks.